# How does one find the caret position (in screen-space or form-space) in a WPF textbox?

Tags: wpf, wpfdatagrid

As the title suggests, how do I find the caret position of a WPF textbox *in screen or form-space coordinates*?  So far, I've only been able to find how to get the character position of the caret in the textbox.

Perhaps I'm getting ahead of myself though, because really, I'm trying to ensure that the current caret position of the selected TextBox (of dynamic height) contained within a DataGrid is visible to the user.  So, if there's a way to do this without knowing the coordinates of the caret, then I'm all ears.  So far, I've tried calling the DataGrid's ScrollIntoView method, but this can fail if the TextBox is taller than the available screen space.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can do it natively, but you call use interop to call the Win32 GetGUIThreadInfo(). See here for an example: [How to call GetGUIThreadInfo in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3072974/how-to-call-getguithreadinfo-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest something but I don't know if it is applicable in your case. I needed to create a triangular caret to replace the vertical-line caret of a WPF textbox. I control its location with a translate transform and it is always following the default textbox caret. In this way you know where is your new caret is inside the text box (by knowing the X and Y of its translate transform) and then you can use PointToScreen to convert it to screen coordinates.